# Understanding a Python execution using 'top' in Ubuntu

Tags: python

When I'm executing a Python script. The following screen is what shows the 'top' command:

[image]

Tell me if I'm wrong or not: The screen shows that the Python script execution is taking one entire Core (%CPU: 100%), and the rest cores are using for others executions (actually sleepting)?

I'm using a Macbook Pro 10.6 with Intel Core i5.
Thnks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python script is a single process and so can only use one core. 
You have to specifically code it to use multiple cores using something like parallel python

Comment: And the Python script is taking the entire core, right? Can you also tell me why do people vote negative to my question? I can't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it is. Err it's a pretty basic question so I think they probably thought you could have found out for yourself. No problem

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it next time. Thanks Anake.